# Should "Your Reputation" be placed more prominently?

Tags: feature-request, design, reputation

I had a hard time finding "Your Reputation" on the [Privileges](https://ux.stackexchange.com/privileges) page. I suppose that's due to it's position on the right column. The right column might be interpreted as non important information. I was reading the general explanation text and tried to find my actual privileges on different places.

Possible Solutions:

- Columns with same width
- "Your Reputation" on the left. Explanation on the right.
- Extending: "Click on any privilege **on the right column** to learn more about it."

Comment: Is anyone from SE reading this? it would be nice to get acknowledgement if they are going to do this or some sort of response with a request denial in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at them, I like your second bullet point:

[image]

Not sure how willing they would be regarding making this change, unless that page has its own stylesheet used for overrides, but it's pretty trivial to flip the two columns in general. The only concern is that the HTML "frame" used for this page is the same frame as every other page on the site (and actually, on all SE sites).

Comment: I like this simple flip. The first thing I read now is "Your Reputation" and the score.If the explanations of the Priviliges are inbetween e. g. "trusted user" and "63%" the usual layout could be used. And we wouldn't have to wait for mouse over explanations.